# Верстка flexbox, передвинуть флекс элемент внутри контейнера

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

Здравствуйте. Никак не могу разобраться как решить такую задачу. Верстаю блок - сверху картинка, под ней текст. И все хорошо,но картинка первого блока чуть больше других, и поэтому текст под ней уезжает вниз. Возможно ли внутри флекс контейнера поднять только один элемент, чтобы текст выровнялся с остальным? Какие могут быть решения этой задачки?

HTML

```
<div class="about_img">
<div class="about_item">
<img src="">
<span class="img_text">текст</span>
</div>
<div class="about_item">
<img src="">
<span class="img_text">текст</span>
</div>
<div class="about_item">
<img src="">
<span class="img_text">текст</span>
</div>
<div class="about_item">
<img src="">
<span class="img_text">текст</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.about_img {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
justify-content: flex-start; }

.about_item {
position: relative;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
font-family: FRAMDCN; 
font-size:18pt;
line-height:1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
.about_item{
 ....
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.about_item span{
 display:block;
 height: 100px;
}
```

Тогда все картинки прижмутся к верхней границе родительского блока, а тексты к нижней.

Comment: в таком случае,получается слишком большой отступ между текстом и картинками,которые меньшего размера. И почему-то пропадает часть текста

Comment: Высоту отступа можно настроить высотой родительского контейнера в комбинации с высотой `.about_item span`. Часть текста пропадает из-за того, что я сделал спан блочным элементом. В любом случае, придется что-нибудь зафиксировать: либо высоту картинки, либо размеры родительского контейнера.

Comment: кажется, что я слишком все усложнила. Проблема решилась простым применением justify-content: flex-end